# iOS Loading Custom Annotations

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, annotations, mapkit

I've built an app that displays facilities and users on the map. Both, facility and users are custom annotations (I've extended `MKPointAnnotation`). I've also enabled callouts, left and right callout accessory views for both the types of **annotations**. The geo and other meta data for these objects are loaded from my Parse database in background. I have seen a recommendation in many places that says you should load all the annotations in `viewDidLoad()`. While that seems reasonable, I am wondering if that's the right approach where I want to quickly load and display what's in user's current region.

My current approach is this: load a set of annotations in `viewDidLoad()`based on user's current location. In my regionDidChange method for the MapView delegate, I perform search, remove all annotations and add them again. This largely works but occasionally I get facility's accessory views assigned to user's annotation. I've checked everything several times it seems to be related to timing and happens when user pans the map while annotations are being added/displayed. It doesn't happen in the debugger. I suspect that's to do with I'm reloading the annotations when user changes his/her region.

I would like to get some feedback on if I'm fundamentally loading the annotations incorrectly and how should I model it to dynamically load/display annotation as user moves the location, or pans on the map. I've seen Redfin loading properties as user pans the map, though I don't know if they have multiple types of custom annotations.

Thank you for all the help!

Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

http://swift3devlopment.blogspot.in/ here have some stuff that you actually need..

Comment: Thanks but I could not find any specific reference to loading multiple custom annotations dynamically as user pans through the map.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Create class like below

```
  class custumAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation
    {
        var imgName : String?

    }
```

step 2 : go to your Viewcontroller.swift and write code as a following

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView : MKMapView!
    var CLManager = CLLocationManager()
    var flag : Int = 0
     var tag : Int = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CLManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.4575
            , longitude: 73.8677)

        let center1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.5597
            , longitude: 73.7799)
        let point1 = custumAnnotation()
        point1.coordinate = center
        point1.imgName = "1.png"
        point1.title = "First"
        point1.subtitle = "Subtitle1"

        let point2  = custumAnnotation()
        point2.coordinate = center1
        point2.imgName = "2.png"
        point2.title = "Second"
        point2.subtitle = "Subtitle2"

        mapView.addAnnotation(point1)
        mapView.addAnnotation(point2)
        mapView.delegate = self
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {

        if(flag == 0)
        {
            flag=1
            let userLocation  = userLocation.location?.coordinate

            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (userLocation?.latitude)!
                , longitude: (userLocation?.longitude)!)

            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            mapView.showsUserLocation = false

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = center
            annotation.title = "ME"
            annotation.subtitle = "CD"
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {



        if !(annotation is custumAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if anView == nil
        {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else
        {
            anView?.annotation = annotation

        }

        let cpa = annotation as! custumAnnotation
        anView?.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imgName!)
        anView?.tag = tag
        tag = tag + 1
        return anView
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        print(view.tag)

    }
}
```